# Scala Slick connection to MySQL database using InteliJ-IDE

Tags: mysql, database, scala, intellij-idea, slick

How can i connect to MySQL database using Scala Slick library on the InteliJ IDE?
Can't find any examples. I can succesfully connect to a PostgreSQL database with the example below, but any ideas how to connect to MySQL or SQLite?

```
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val connectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/scala_test?user=postgres&password=kurmis"
        println("Postgresql oppened ")

        Database.forURL(connectionUrl, driver = "org.postgresql.Driver") withSession {
          implicit session =>
val users = TableQuery[testas]
        for (a <- 1 to 100) {
          val r = scala.util.Random
users.map(u => (u.nr, u.pirmas, u.antras, u.trecias, u.ketvirtas, u.penktas, u.sestas, u.septinas, u.astuntas, u.devintas)
      )+= (a, r.nextInt.toString, r.nextInt.toString, r.nextInt.toString, r.nextInt.toString,
        r.nextInt.toString, r.nextInt.toString, r.nextInt.toString, r.nextInt.toString, r.nextInt.toString)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running my Slick-Play App using

in `application.conf`

```
mysql {
  slick.driver=scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver
  driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDBNAME?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
  user=""
  password=""
}
```

Make sure you have included `mysql-connector-java` as sbt dependency

And then in my app I use:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("mysql")
```